# No me funciona Booststrap 5

Tags: html5, bootstrap

He descargado Booststrap 5 en mi computadora pero al momento de cargar mi pagina los estilos y las funciones de Booststrap no funcionan, no se que pasa las rutas están bien, es que acaso es un problema de la versión ??

para los estilos Css enlace el archivo: **bootstrap.min.css**

para los archivos Js enlace el archivo: **bootstrap.bundle.min.js**

Así es como estoy enlazando Bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Bootstrap/Css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Y ese CSS sí está en esa ruta relativa?

Comment: Si cree la carpeta booststrap y adentro cree otras dos carpetas llamada Css y Js y en Css agregue ese archivo el : bootstrap.min.css. Lo estoy llamado desde otro archivo que esta dentro de una carpeta por eso los 2 puntos ..

Comment: ¿Algún error en la consola?

Comment: No ninguno amigo

Comment: Debes crear un [mre] para estos casos. Si no se puede replicar el error, tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada.